# EF Core V6 slow query performance in Azure web app after upgrade from .NET core 3.1 to .Net Core 6

Tags: performance, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

We recently updated our .Net core project from .Net core 3.1 to 6, along with this we upgraded EntityFrameworkCore from V 3.1.3 to V 6.0.8.

We then noticed queries performing extremely poorly in our Azure web app and I can't tell why.

Our web-app memory and CPU are not under strain and our Database generally averages 50% DTU usage with occasional spikes.

We had a query that initially ran under 5 seconds to now running 30+ seconds, sometimes into the minutes with the exact same data set.

Also, when running the same query on my local with the exact same data its also under 5 seconds. I used SQL profiler to see the generated query and copied the EF generated query and ran it on production and it completed in under a second.

The Linq query is provided below:

```
            var ids = notifications.Select(x => x.GroupId).ToList();
            var groups = await dbContext.Groups
                .Include(g => g.UserGroups)
                .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.GroupId)).ToListAsync();
            return groups;
```

This is not the only impacted query so far, I have spotted some others that have degraded in performance.

I would appreciate some guidance on finding the root cause of the issue, alternatively would it be a case-by-case basis whereby we need to individually re-write certain queries because EF core changed how certain queries are generated now?

Tried running queries in production expecting the same performance or better than we had before releasing the .Net core upgrade but the opposite seems to have occurred (at least for some queries)

Comment: Are you logging performance metrics around this one particular EF call?
Have you tried a synchronous call with logged metrics to compare to the `async` performance? (in case threads are getting throttled)

Comment: We are logging metrics in Azure app insights, I have not tried a sync call yes but its worth a try. We can definitely improve the query but it strikes me as odd that it degraded after the upgrade